# How can I move dates returned in a select statement and redesign the table to have them as columns?

Tags: sql, t-sql, select

I have a table being returned from a sql stored procedure that returns Date, Name, Subject, and Amount.  I want each distinct date that is returned to be a column in the output.  So, say the date range I pass the stored procedure is 1/1/2013 to 1/5/2013.  I would want the table to be returned as Name, Subject, 1/1/2013, 1/2/2013, 1/3/2013, 1/4/2013, and 1/5/2013.  How can I go about this?

Comment: Which version of SQL Server (if 2005 or higher), you can use the PIVOT command

Comment: How does your output look like? How did you try to output it in desired way?

Comment: @Sparky I'm reading up on the pivot command right now.  But every example I have, they have an idea of which rows need to be pivoted.  In my case I have no idea what date value I'm going to get.  How could I do this in my case?

Comment: do you want the dates to be column headers or actual data for each row.

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18317732/sql-server-pivot-table-with-joins-and-dynamic-columns question

Comment: @stackuser I want the dates to go from being data in a table to being column headers

Answer (score 0):

SELECT date,name,subject,amount into #tmp from [your table]

DECLARE @DDATE DATE
DECLARE @SQLQ NVARCHAR(500)

DECLARE DT_CURSOR CURSOR FOR 
SELECT DISTINCT DATE FROM #tmp
OPEN DT_CURSOR
FETCH NEXT FROM DT_CURSOR INTO @DDATE
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS=0
BEGIN
    SET @SQLQ = 'ALTER TABLE #TMP ADD ['+REPLACE(RTRIM(LTRIM(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),REPLACE(@DDATE,'-','')))),' ','')+'] VARCHAR(50)'
    EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQLQ
    FETCH NEXT FROM DT_CURSOR INTO @DDATE
END
CLOSE DT_CURSOR
DEALLOCATE DT_CURSOR
SELECT * FROM #TMP
DROP TABLE #TMP

You have not told how the data should group in new columns. this just creates Column for every distinct date.