# tsql pivot help - need help pivoting dialer stats

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

i cant figure this out for the life of me -

```
   select 
*


from
(
    select 
Columnno 
,dt 
,Loans 
,[Dials Attempted]
,dpl
,aband
,contact
,success
,conv
--,case when dt is not null then 1

from 


   data
) sourcetable
```

this query will produce results as

[image]

my desired results would be

[image]

ive tried a few things but it just errors out, help, im lost. Thanks in advance.

Comment: To do this you will have to use dynamic sql in order to construct list of columns to be displayed. The problem is already solved - please check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18317732/sql-server-pivot-table-with-joins-and-dynamic-columns

Comment: @MaciejNowicki thanks, ill look at the link in a bit, i ended up figuring it out. posted answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what i ended up doing

:

```
select 

labels, [1],[2]

from(
    select 
    *
    ,case when labels = 'Date' then 1 
            when labels = 'Loans' then 2
                When labels = 'Dials Attempted' then 3
                    when labels ='DPL' then 4
                        when labels = 'Abandoned' then 5
                            when labels = 'Contacts' then 6
                                when labels = 'Success' then 7
                                    when labels ='Conversion' then 8
                                        end rownum


    from
    (
        select 

        convert(varchar, Columnno ) Columnno
     ,convert(varchar, dt ) Date
        ,convert(varchar, Loans ) Loans
        ,convert(varchar, [Dials Attempted]) 'Dials Attempted'
        ,convert(varchar, dpl) DPL
        ,convert(varchar, aband) Abandoned
        ,convert(varchar, contact) Contacts
        ,convert(varchar, success) Success
        ,convert(varchar, conv) Conversion
        --,case when dt is not null then 1

        from 
        data
    ) sourcetable


    unpivot ( [Data] for  labels in (Date,Loans, [Dials Attempted], DPL, Abandoned, Contacts, Success, Conversion ) ) pivots) sourced

pivot( max(Data) for Columnno in ([1],[2])) pvt

order by rownum
```

This is what it produced

[image]

Comment: It's OK, but if you want to have more than 2 columns containing values, you have to modify query or use dynamic SQL as i've said before.

Cheers!

BTW. You should not answer your own question - you should modify your original question adding results of research.